# Flex: How to access movieclips from an imported swf

Tags: apache-flex, movieclip

What are the steps necessary to access movieclips from an imported swf within a Flex application?

Comment: How are you importing the SWF?  Are you embedding it as a class, or using a Loader/SWFLoader?  A concrete example of what you are trying to do would greatly help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm utilizing the SWFLoader, which allows me to import the swf into the application, but I don't see a way of accessing the movieclips within that swf.